# Using DLL's in Visual Studio 2010 C++ project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll

I am trying to use a DLL in a Visual Studio 2010 C++ project . I followed the directions here but http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(v=vs.80).aspx I cannot seem to add references to my project.

When I open add reference there is no way for me to add any references, as shown below. 
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

You are using the wrong version of the tutorial. It is created for Visual Studio 2005 and you are using Visual Studio 2010. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is the correct version.

Comment: I'm seeing the same directions on the 2010 version as well. It's still saying to: "To use the math routines that were created in the dynamic link library, you must reference the library. To do this, select the MyExecRefsDll project in the Solution Explorer, then select References… from the Project menu."

Nothing is showing up for me either after adding a path to the .dll and .lib file from Visual Stuio.

Comment: Why is this answer getting six upvotes?  StackOverflow encourages helpful answers, not just providing a link.  Besides, I'm not sure that link is too helpful anyway.

Comment: Considering that the original question is about a linked tutorial on MSDN, answering with a linked tutorial on MSDN seems fine. The answer *is* bullshit but not for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here (I think) is that you didn't "add to solution" when creating the project that will utilize the dll file.

edit: or you might have forgotten to compile your dll